Find the sphere touching the cone
Hi I am puzzled by the last part of this question where it asks me to find the radius and centre of the sphere. I would have thought infinite spheres would touch the specified circle  Am I wrong? Is this part of the exercise flawed? It says the answer is radius $15$ and centre $(0,0,9)$
"A right circular cone has vertex at the point $V(0, 0, 16)$ and the centre of its base at the origin $O$. The points $A, B, C$ lie on the circumference of the base, which is of radius $12$ units. $A$ is on the positive $x$-axis and $B$ is on the positive $y$-axis. The point $C$ is on the minor arc $AB$ and $AOC$ is an equilateral triangle. Find the equations of
a) the line VA
b) the line VC
c) the plane VAC
A sphere has its centre on the z axis and the cone touches the sphere along the circle $ACB$. Find the radius of the sphere and the coordinates of its centre."

Please show what you tried. Also, using mathjax would give a better shape to the question.

The center has to be at $(0,0,-9)$. The sphere has to "touch" the cone, meaning it's tangent to it, not to "intersect" the cone.

Ah ok thanks it seems my misunderstanding might stem from my misinterpretation of the word "touch"

I was just curious if you succeeded in solving the problem

Yes I did Andrei, thanks , your comment helped greatly in clarifying for me what the question required
